# How to turn off dates and/or people in Facebook's "On This Day"?

Tags: facebook

Facebook's "On This Day" is an interesting way to surface things that I, or people who I'm friends with, have shared in the past. However, there are some memories that I'd rather not be surfaced. (A funeral, perhaps, or a friend with whom I've had a falling out.)

Is there a way to control which dates and/or people appear on "On This Day"? (I don't want to block people, nor avoid Facebook on a particular day.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

1. Go to https://www.facebook.com/onthisday
2. You should have two buttons in the upper right. Click "Preferences".
   [image: "Notifications" and "Preferences" on "On This Day" page]
3. On the Preferences pane you can add dates and/or people that you would like to ***not*** appear in "On This Day".
   [image: "On This Day" Preferences window]

The text on the Preferences pane says:

> Your memories are yours, so you should control which ones you see in On This Day. Memories include things like your posts and others' posts you're tagged in, major life events and when you became friends with someone on Facebook. Use these filters to help make sure we show you memories from On This Day in a way that's meaningful for you.

---

If you want to keep from being reminded about "On This Day" altogether, click "Notifications", then "Off".